# Break up large number of rows in a single column to multiple columns

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a 1542 rows in a single column.

I would like to break this up into multiple columns with the same # or close to same number of rows in each column.  Also if possible be able to do this different ways...

i.e. break it up into 4,5,6 or more columns 
my data is IP addresses so it would be text in each cell
below is sample of my data

```
10.11.6.1
10.11.8.1
10.11.11.1
10.11.22.1
10.11.26.1
10.11.32.1
10.11.35.1
10.11.38.1
10.18.8.1
10.18.14.1
10.18.19.1
10.18.24.1
10.18.25.1
10.18.27.1
10.18.73.1
10.18.86.1
10.18.88.1
10.19.8.1
10.19.19.1
10.19.29.1
10.19.31.1
10.19.43.1
10.19.54.1
10.19.57.1
10.19.65.1
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple vba script to take the value in a selected cell and break it into separate cells is:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim rCell As Range, cString As String, cr As String
    Set rCell = Selection(1)
    a = rCell.Value
    cr = Chr(13)
    If InStr(a, cr) > 0 Then
        ary = Split(a, cr)
        For i = 1 To UBound(ary)
            rCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
        Next i
        For i = 0 To UBound(ary)
            rCell.Offset(i, 0).Value = ary(i)
        Next i
    End If

End Sub
```

This macro finds char(13), carriage return, and adds new cell based on finding it.  If this does not work you may have char(10), line feeds, so just change the number in the macro.

This macro is plagiarized in part from other posts both on this and other forums

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim v As String, Old As String
    Dim N As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    j = 2
    i = 1
    Cells(1, 2) = Cells(1, 1)
    Old = Split(Cells(i, 1), ".")(1)

    For k = 2 To N
        v = Cells(k, 1).Value
        If Split(v, ".")(1) <> Old Then
            j = j + 1
            i = 1
            Old = Split(v, ".")(1)
        Else
            i = i + 1
        End If
        Cells(i, j) = v
    Next k
End Sub
```

[image]